# Add content to HTML file programmaticaly in iOS

Tags: html, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I would like to add some content(dynamic) received via web-service  to an existing local HTML file and then display it in web view. But I'm not being able to figure out how to add the content to a local HTML file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean to say you need to build HTML on the basis of result coming from the web-service?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value using javaScript like this

```
    NSURL *indexFileURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"name_of_your_local_html" withExtension:@"html"];
    self.query1=[indexFileURL absoluteString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:indexFileURL];
    [wbView loadRequest:request];
```

Suppose you have a key "myKey" in your HTML

```
<td><span class="fieldVal" id="myKey"></span></td>
```

And Pass value using like this

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *indexFileURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"name_of_your_local_html" withExtension:@"html"];
[wbView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:indexFileURL]];
[wbView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('myKey').innerHTML='%@'",@"myValue"]];
```

Comment: Hey this code is working when I'm pass a 'text' as value, but when I pass a HTML string it is not working :|.

Comment: Do you have a static HTML with dynamic value?

Comment: I have a local html page with a div having content "%value%". I'm trying to load the html page to webview, then replace "%value%" by an HTML string (pretty big) which is dynamic.